# How to save state of GET request url java spring rest

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have RESTful app which reacts on   `GET request` and I need to store the state.

For example

```
localhost/subs?search=John
```

Then I need to add other parameter `division` by clicking button.

```
localhost/subs?search=John&division=develop
```

Meanwhile the data output will be distributed on pages. And appear new 2 parameters size and page.

```
localhost/subs?search=John&division=develop&size=5&page=0
```

In this situation when I click on next page button my url is resetting.
I’m really confused. How to save state and if parameter is already has in url then it should be changed for new value, if parameter doesn’t exist then append it.

If there good options?
At least I can use JavaScript by taking it and parsing url.
But I think it’s not good at all.

Comment: Sounds more like a frontend issue imo, Also this question lacks a lot of context/detail to give you any useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the RestAPI doesn't save any request parameters (Maybe you can do by adding them into a session attribute, but it's just made the logic code become more complex).

> At least I can use JavaScript by taking it and parsing URL

Yes, I think you should.

Happy coding!

Comment: May be I can generate my links depending on what the current parameters are?
If link will be `localhost/subs/search=John` in thymeleaf framework every time the webpage is generating i check if there's search parameter exist? `${#request.getParameter('search')}` but my url will contain search will no parameter
`localhost/subs?search=&size=5&page=0` hmmm, seems bad?